# Hallar índices de valores en una lista de python

Tags: python, lista

Supongamos que se tienen las listas:

```
lst    = [0.818362  0.115443    0   0   0.0507871   0.609459    0   0]
values = [0.0596643 0.673551    0.712858    0.61972 0.818362    0.115443    0.539705    0.0507871   0.609459]
```

y se desea hallar todos los índices de los valores en la lista `values` que hay en `lst`. El output resultante sería:

```
idx = [4 5 7 8]
```

¿Es posible realizar esto de alguna forma a traves de `values.index(lst)`?

Comment: Prueba con  `[e for e in lst if e in values]`, el único tema son los alores de coma flotante, que eventualmente puede no coincidir exactamente, no respondo, por que ya debe haber varias respuestas para este problema.

Comment: Gracias! pruebo ahora.

Comment: ¿Son verdaderamente listas?, eso tiene pinta (por la representación) de arrays de Numpy, ¿es así? Lo digo porque la aproximación buscando la eficiencia puede diferir mucho...

Comment: Si, son numpy arrays, pero los convierto en listas previamente. Realmente, es una matriz y he de encontrar los indices en la lista de cada valor de la matriz. En el ejemplo solo he puesto una de las filas de la matriz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usar `list.index` como comentas, aunque posible (*) es ineficiente, además de tener que recorrer `values` por cada item de `lst` hay que manejar las excepciones `ValueError` que tendremos cuando el item no exista.

```
lst    = [0.818362,  0.115443, 0, 0, 0.0507871, 0.609459, 0, 0]
values = [0.0596643, 0.673551, 0.712858, 0.61972, 0.818362,
          0.115443, 0.539705, 0.0507871, 0.609459
          ]

indices = []
for item in lst:
    try:
        index = values.index(item)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        indices.append(index)
```

(*) Esta aproximación tiene otro problema que hay que tener en cuenta, `list.index` retorna el primer índice que encuentra con ese valor, de tener valores repetidos en valores tendremos un problema:

```
lst    = [0, 2, 7]
values = [5, 2, 8, 2, 7, 2, 7]

for item in lst:
    #....

>>> indices
[1, 4]
```

Se puede solucionar pero complicamos todo aún más y hay mejores opciones.

Otra aproximación es usar `enumerate` para obtener las parejas `(indice, valor)` de `values` y comprobar si el valor está en `lst`, añadiendo en tal caso el índice a la lista. Podemos usar una lista por compresión para mejorar la eficiencia. Además, dado que las búsquedas en listas son ineficientes por naturaleza, podemos pasar `lst` a un conjunto, dado que las búsquedas en tablas hash son mucho más eficientes:

```
lst    = [0.818362,  0.115443, 0, 0, 0.0507871, 0.609459, 0, 0]
values = [0.0596643, 0.673551, 0.712858, 0.61972, 0.818362,
          0.115443, 0.539705, 0.0507871, 0.609459
          ]
lst_set = set(lst)
indices = [index for index, valor in enumerate(values) if valor in lst_set]
```

> ```
> >>> indices
> [4, 5, 7, 8]
> ```

En este caso, ante repeticiones:

> ```
> lst    = [0, 2, 7]
> values = [5, 2, 8, 2, 7, 2, 7]
>
> lst_set = set(lst)
> indices = [index for index, valor in enumerate(values) if valor in lst_set]
>
> >>> indices
> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> ```

Por último, en el caso de usar NumPy, podemos recurrir a [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) que nos retorna un filtro boleano (array del tamaño de `values` en el que tenemos `True` si ese valor existe en `lst` y `False` en caso contrario). Podemos recuperar los índices aplicando `numpy.where` a dicho array simplemente:

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.array((0.818362,  0.115443, 0, 0, 0.0507871, 0.609459, 0, 0))
values = np.array(
    (0.0596643, 0.673551, 0.712858, 0.61972, 0.818362,
     0.115443, 0.539705, 0.0507871, 0.609459)
     )

indices = np.where(np.isin(values, lst, assume_unique=True))[0]
```

> ```
> >>> indices
> array([4, 5, 7, 8])
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Con el último método, a través de ````np.where()``` funciona a la perfección. Realmente no me interesa tanto la eficiencia puesto que en este caso estoy tratando de analizar la progresión numérica que siguen los índices obtenidos.